# How to check if URL query strings, fragments, etc actually change webpage content for end users?

Tags: python, html, url

I'm writing an app which allows people to discuss a webpage together if they are on the same webpage. The actual app works fine and is interesting to use, but sometimes the app mistakenly believes the two individuals are on different URLs while in content/practical purposes they are on the same page. If I store the entire URL and simply compare it to the other URL that the second user is on, sometimes the URL is clearly different while the webpage content is identical for the end user. Usually this is because sites make different use of the query, fragment, and parameter strings in the URL in different ways. For example, `https://www.facebook.com/zuck?fref=ts` and `https://www.facebook.com/zuck` should be treated as identical webpages for the use of my app since the end user content is indiscernably identical. Facebook uses query strings to understand how you arrived to that certain profile. However, other sites such as YouTube clearly use the query string for the actual content identification such as `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ` so I can't just write a program that is agnostic to URL query or fragment strings etc.

What is the best way to approach this webpage comparison dilemma in python? I have tried different ways such as comparing the source of the two pages using the requests library found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), but the sources are expectedly different. Things I've tried are comparisons such as:

```
if requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/zuck?fref=ts').content == requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/zuck').content:
```

I assume something in the served ads on the sidebars or headers of the page etc is not the same to yield True for a simple '==' comparison.

Any ideas on how to approach this issue? I really appreciate it.

Comment: I would consider trying to match the page title as one of the predicates.

Comment: This is a good idea that slipped my mind. Thanks for bringing it up. However, perhaps it would be a good idea to check for path similarities first and then check the title if and only if there is a query in on of the urls?